# Accessing settings-data in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to access the data from the "settings-app" on the iPhone.
I want to get the "Cellular Network Data" usage information. 
(Settings -- General -- Usage -- Cellular Usage -- Cellular Network Data)
This would be best if I could get the data in Integer-form in xcode.
So what I want is the code needed to extract the data.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: We do not need yet another application that shows you how much data you used

Comment: Maybe you could answer my question instead of hatin' ? Would really help alot :)

Comment: Not hating, just saying that we have enough now. Same for the "Txt replacements" like whatsapp and the emoji enablers.